# 'inputParser' undefined in octave

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, octave

I am trying to use `findpeaks()` function from `signal` package in octave. I have installed and loaded `signal` and `control` packages and now when I try to run `[pks3 idx3] = findpeaks(X,"DoubleSided","MinPeakHeight",0.5);` , I get the following error.

> warning: the 'inputParser' function is not yet implemented in Octave
>
> Please read http://www.octave.org/missing.html to learn how you can
>   contribute missing functionality.
>
> error: 'inputParser' undefined near line 109 column 12 error: called
>   from: error:   /home/kenden/octave/signal-1.3.2/findpeaks.m at line
>   109, column 10

Data X is in this format - `762 660 660 ...`
Is there any work around for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inputParser was implemented in GNU Octave 4.0 so it looks like you are using an older version. Either update Octave or downgrade signal.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a workaround by using `peakdet` function from [here.](http://www.billauer.co.il/peakdet.html)